# problem with my git repo, I lost all my commits?

Tags: linux, git

I was trying to upload a file via terminal.I am trying to learn git.
**

- git add /Users/serra/Documents/useSDWebImage
- git commit -m "learning on process"
- git remote add origin
- git push -u origin master

**
*then I got this message error: failed to push some refs to ....*
I tried those commands then I have only the file I want to upload
to repository I have lost rest of the repository.What should I do?
**

- git pull --rebase origin main
- git push origin main
- git pull origin master
- git push origin master
- git push origin    master --force

**

Comment: What was in the remote repo before? What do you mean by "I have only the file I want to upload to repository I have lost rest of the repository."? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Check if you have both `main` and `master` branches on GitHub. One of them might still contain the old history.

Comment: As a diagnostic, can you edit to show the results of `git status` ; `git whatchanged` ; and `git config --list`...this would help determine the state of the index and local repository... when you did `git remote add origin url` did you use the correct url, or did you really leave the url blank?

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Don’t panic rebase or reset. Also just because a push failed doesn’t mean the commits have been lost.

Comment: It would help if you showed the output of the various commands you ran. The last one you showed, `git push origin master --force` might have been the mistake because it would overwrite the master branch on the remote, which is generally not a good idea. (Hint, never use `push --force` unless you know exactly what you're doing and why you're doing it.)

Comment: Also, can you help us by telling us what branches actually exist on your remote?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

You need to find a backup, somewhere, of `origin/master`.

`git reflog` might help you.

**The error**

First, let's go over your first four commands and explain what the mistake was.

In the first two commands, a git add and git commit, you are creating a commit in your local sandbox, building on whatever was in your sandbox beforehand.

In the third command, you add your remote, which means that your commit was not made on top of that remote, but on top of something else.

In your fourth command, Git correctly tells you that you cannot push, because your local sandbox is not built on top of the remote. It's important to pay attention to Git's error messages, they're almost always informative.

Now, you're not showing outputs from any of the commands you ran, but I'm guessing `git push origin master --force` is what deleted stuff on your remote.

**What you should have done**

Normally, you clone the remote first, then commit stuff on top of it:

```
git clone <URL>
cd <SANDBOX_DIR>
git add <file inside this directory>
git commit
git push
```

**How to fix this**

There are several ways, but they're all based on recovering stuff from a backup that hopefully exists somewhere.

If your remote is GitHub, it keeps a history of references, you should be able to find that old `master` branch somehow there. If your remote is some other server, that is hopefully true too. If another team member has a sandbox that had the valid `master` you want to restore, they can fix things by doing a `git push origin master --force` in their own sandbox, but make sure they understand what they're doing before they do it.

My answer here is not complete, because you didn't provide enough information. I will update it if you update your question with more details about your remote.

**Update - `git reflog` might help**

When you did `git pull origin master`, assuming `master` is the branch you care about, you probably got a local copy of the correct `master` commit you want on `origin`. You can use `git reflog` to see the history of your local HEAD in your sandbox. If you find the good commit there, this solution could work:

Here I'm assuming these is not work you want to preserve in your sandbox.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <good commit> # WARNING: destroys any uncommitted local changes
```

At this point, check that your sandbox contains the files you want to restore to origin. If so, proceed with this command:

```
git push --force origin master
```

But be warned, this will overwrite what's on origin. It's only appropriate if you have carefully validated that `master` in your sandbox really contains the history you want to restore on origin.